# Dealing with TCCRx

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I am totally beginner in Arduino, and i want to ask some questions :

```
    TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & ~(0x07<<CS10)) | (2<<CS10);
```

What does the previous line mean? with good explaination please .

```
    TCCR1A &= ~(3<<COM1A0);
```

for the previous line , is there difference if i wrote '1' instead of '3' ? why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first line, you clear some bits, then set some bits in the same “region” of the byte.

From inside out, get 7 (which is 3 bits of ones: 00000111), shift it upwards (the << operation) by CS10 amount (we don’t know how much, but the compiler does), complement all that (the tilde ~ character) and bitwise ‘and’ it with the value of the TCCR1A register (the & operation). Next, take a 2 (binary 00000010), shift it up by CS10 bits again (<< CS10), and bitwise ‘or’ that bit pattern with the earlier result (the | operator). Finally, assign all that to TCCR1A.

For the second line, yes, changing 3 to 1 will certainly change what happens to TCCR1A. It makes a different bit pattern, and I'm sure you can reason it out after reading the previous explanation.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, I am surprised that I looked so much to find a site with a good explanation and I have not found!
Thank you